# not able to access Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc namespace in ASP .Net Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two solutions connected to each other in ASP .Net Core 6 application. First Solution name is Webinternal and other is Core. In Webinternal Solution I am able to Access Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc namesapce so that I am able to use Remote Attribute.
[Webinternal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOGeE.png)

On the other hand in Core Solution I am not able to Access Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, not able to use Remote Attribute. [core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEHSZ.png)

please help me to sort out this issue

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try as below in your class library project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 ........
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) for more details